# Nuxt 3 build.chunkSizeWarningLimit

Tags: nuxt.js, vite, chunks, code-splitting, nuxt3

When I run npm run build with nuxt 3, it keeps giving me this warning

```
Some chunks are larger than 500 kBs after minification. Consider:
Using dynamic import() to code-split the application
- Use build.rollupOptions.output.manualChunks to improve chunking: https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#output-manualchunks
- Adjust chunk size limit for this warning via build.chunkSizeWarningLimit.
```

In previous projects where I used vue and vite it was simple to fix with setting chunkSizeWarningLimit., but for nuxt 3 none of this seems to work

Please help me. Some chunks are larger than 500 kBs after minification